# How to transmit a new value got with a scale to another function?

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter, tkinter-scale

I'm on Python2.7 and I try to transmit a value got from a `scale`, to another function which has to respond to a click.

```
from tkinter import * 

fenetre = Tk()

def other(ev):
    m=2
    l=3
    vol_piano=maj()
    print(vol_piano)

def maj(newvalue):
    vol_piano = newvalue
    print(vol_piano)
    return vol_piano

value = DoubleVar()
scale = Scale(fenetre, variable=value, orient ='vertical', from_ = 0, to= 100,
              resolution = 1, tickinterval= 5, length=400, label='Volume Piano',command=maj)
scale.pack(side=RIGHT)

canvas = Canvas(fenetre, width=100, height=400, bg="white")
curseur1 = canvas.create_line(0, 0, 0, 0)
canvas.pack(side=LEFT)
canvas.bind("<Button-1>", other)

fenetre.mainloop()
```

The problem is that I can't use return because my function `maj()` has in argument the new value got with scale.

Comment: You could make `vol_piano` a global variable.

Comment: Yes  I tried but because of fenetre.mainloop(), vol_piano will be always initialized as the basic value I gave...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make `vol_piano` a global variable. Update its value whenever `Scale` is moved inside the `maj()` function. Whenever the canvas is clicked, just print out the value of `vol_piano`.

```
import tkinter as tk

fenetre = tk.Tk()

vol_piano = None

def other(ev):
    global vol_piano
    print(vol_piano)

def maj(newvalue):
    global vol_piano
    vol_piano = newvalue

value = tk.DoubleVar()
scale = tk.Scale(fenetre, variable=value, orient ='vertical', from_ = 0, to= 100,
              resolution = 1, tickinterval= 5, length=400, label='Volume Piano',command=maj)
scale.pack(side="right")

canvas = tk.Canvas(fenetre, width=100, height=400, bg="white")
canvas.pack(side="left")
canvas.bind("<Button-1>", other)

fenetre.mainloop()
```